# Qt Creator5.0.2 runs an error dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifCloseFile

Tags: qt, qt-creator, dylib

#### This is the error in MacOS 11.5

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifCloseFile
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

- But I didn't find libGIF.dylib under this path ***/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources*** in MacOS11.5，i find it under this path in MacOS10.xx
- I tried many methods, but does anyone know why?

Comment: It's in the dyld_shared_cache, but idk how that would help you...

Comment: @Siguza Very happy, I solved this problem by upgrading  to macOS 12.3